# Pandas Dataframe Group-by columns not working in Matplotlib Barplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a data that contains suicides, year by year and country by country and more. I grouped them by age and country but by doing that i think country and age are becoming indexes and that is why I cant use them on `barplot`. Here is the code.

```
spe = df.groupby(['country','age']).sum().sort_values(by='suicides_no').xs(level='age',
                                                                          key='15-24 years')
sns.barplot(x = 'country', y = 'suicides_no',data = spe)
matplotlib.pyplot.xticks(rotation=90)
```

I get this error:

> ValueError: Could not interpret input 'country'

Answer (score 1):

You can turn indicies back into columns `spe = spe.reset_index()`

Answer (score 0):

If you are plotting just one group of age as your `spe` indicates, you can just do:

```
(df[df['age']=='15-24 years'].groupby('country', as_index=False)
     .sort_values('suicides_no')
     .plot.bar(x='country', y='suicides_no')
)
```